# Error when backing up a database in SQL Server 2008 R2

Tags: c#-4.0, sql-server-2008-r2, database-backups

In XP machine, I am using SQL Server 2008 R2 to backup files, that the files are stored in the `c:/ProgramFiles/.../Data` folder, but in this case I got the exception

> Cannot open backup device 'C:\Program Files\Data\BlaBla_123.bak'.
>   Operating system error 5 (failed to retrieve text for this error. Reason: 1815).
>   Msg 3013, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
>   BACKUP DATABASE is terminating abnormally.

My query

```
ALTER DATABASE BlaBla SET SINGLE_USER WITH ROLLBACK IMMEDIATE 
backup database BlaBla to disk = 'C:\Program Files\Data\BlaBla_123.bak'
```

But I know this will work when I stored the backup file in the D drive or something,

My question is, How to save the backup in the Same folder and What I need to do from code side or query side?

Comment: did you read this [kb article](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/290787) ? I guess something outside sqlserver is screwed up....

Comment: @rene : Yes, I get it, need to give Access permission to that folder for SQL login.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I added Network Service (or of the accout that is assigned to the SQL Server service account) with Full Control permission to the ACL (Access Control List) of the backup .bak file.